# php flock with timeout (for LOCK_SH / LOCK_EX )

Tags: php, locking

i want a flock with timeout, unfortunately i haven't found a good way to implement it (like a signaled timeout on an actual blocking request?), so i'm just trying and sleeping until success or timeout, code:

```php
function flockWithTimeout($handle, int $flags, int &$would_block = null, float $timeout_seconds = 10, float $sleep_time_seconds = 0.01): bool
{
    $flags = $flags | LOCK_NB;
    $would_block = null;
    $timeout_timestamp = microtime(true) + $timeout_seconds;
    $sleep_time_microseconds = (int)($sleep_time_seconds * 1000000);
    for (;;) {
        $success = flock($handle, $flags, $would_block);
        if ($success) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!$would_block) {
            // something else is wrong, like flocking on FAT32 which doesn't support flock?
            return false;
        }
        // another process has the lock
        if (microtime(true) >= $timeout_timestamp) {
            return false;
        }
        usleep($sleep_time_microseconds);
    }
    throw new \LogicException('unreachable');
}
```

sample usage:

```php
$h = tmpfile();
$h2 = fopen(stream_get_meta_data($h)['uri'], "rb");
if(flockWithTimeout($h, LOCK_EX)){
    echo "got the lock! :)\n";
} else {
    echo "did not get the lock :(\n";
}
$timeout_seconds = 0.1;
if(flockWithTimeout($h2, LOCK_SH, $would_block, $timeout_seconds)){
    echo "got the lock! :)\n";
} else {
    echo "did not get the lock :(\n";
}
```

should print

```
got the lock! :)
did not get the lock :(
```

with the `did not get the lock :(` taking roughly 100 milliseconds

Comment: wonder if it should have been ```$flags = (($flags & LOCK_UN) ? $flags : ($flags | LOCK_NB));```  PHP does weird stuff with LOCK_UN, ref https://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/comments/uapav7/instead_of_using_the_standard_8_for_lock_un_let/

Comment: I find the way the `$would_block` parameter of the `flockWithTimeout()` function is used strange. It seems to serve no purpose.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware well it ensures that the arguments are compatible with flock's arguments, making it a drop-in replacements. there's also a very obscure use case, detecting if it timed out or if flock failed for some other reason (eg if the function returns false and $would_block is also false, it suggest some error other than timeout, for example trying to flock() on FAT32, or some filesystem without flock support, some networked filesystems doesn't)

Comment: OK, I see, yes, that makes sense. I missed the `&` in front of the `$would_block` argument. It means that it points to a variable outside the function. It will return the value that was set by `flock($handle, $flags, $would_block)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this function looks good. Your choice of variable names is good. I'm not an expert on file locking, but, although valid code, I don't like the `for (;;)` forever loop. Let me try to rewrite that. What about this:

```
function flockWithTimeout($handle, int $flags, int &$would_block = null, float $timeout_seconds = 10, float $sleep_time_seconds = 0.01): bool
{
    $flags = $flags | LOCK_NB;
    $timeout_timestamp = microtime(true) + $timeout_seconds;
    do {
        if (flock($handle, $flags, $would_block)) {
            // success, we got the file lock, we're done
            return true;
        }
        if (!$would_block) {
            // something else is wrong, like flocking on FAT32 which doesn't support flock?
            return false;
        }
        usleep((int)($sleep_time_seconds * 1000000));
    } while (microtime(true) < $timeout_timestamp);
    // timed out, another process has the lock
    return false;
}
```

- There's no need to do `$would_block = null;`.
- Since you're wasting time anyway, I put the computation inside the `usleep()` function. This is debatable...
- I got rid of the exception, sorry, I didn't see the point.
- The `$success` variable wasn't really needed.

Comment: thanks! by the way, i think removing the LOCK_UN check is a mistake, pretty sure the LOCK_NB bits is not supposed to be set for LOCK_UN, and at least in PHP it does make a difference: it's entirely possible that the value 7 doesn't mean anything (i'm not sure): https://3v4l.org/N0eLH